# How to 'Select All' using the keyboard?

Tags: objects

Is there a way - using key commands - to select all?

I have a sphere that has some vertices deep inside that only appear when I move the ball, and they are not selected no mater if I use the <kbd>C</kbd> or the <kbd>B</kbd> select keys.

If I could "select all" the program should be able to get these little rouge vertices that I can not seem to collect when I try either <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>B</kbd>.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**, you can select all with <kbd>A</kbd>.

If there is anything selected then <kbd>A</kbd> will deselect everything, if nothing is selected <kbd>A</kbd> will select everything.  You can change this behavior immediately after pressing <kbd>A</kbd> at the bottom of the <kbd>T</kbd> toolbar, or with the <kbd>F6</kbd> menu.

Comment: This is not correct.  Although the scene window shows all the objects selected, any further commands will only have an affect on the initial objects that were selected by hand.  Effectively, select all only LOOKS like all are selected, when in actuality, only the first hand-selected object is actually selected.

Comment: @tguy no not really.  When multiple objects are selected they really are *all* selected.  But some operations are only applicable to one object at a time, in that case the operations are only applied to the *active object* - the most recent individually selected object (indicated by a slightly lighter orange color).

Answer (score 2):

You could also disable the *Limit selection to visible* option which is enabled by default.

Then circle and box select will also work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another tool that may be helpful is [select linked](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#select-linked). There are two ways to use it -

- pressing <kbd>L</kbd> will select all vertices linked to the vertex under the cursor.
- pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> will select all vertices linked to the currently selected vertices.