# How to select all objects in a scene?

Tags: objects, selection-tools

How do I select everything that is inside of my scene OBJECT wise? I have too many objects in my scene for me to select them all with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd>

Comment: How about pressing `A` once ow twice (depending on whether something already was selected) ? You might want to unhide everything hidden with `Alt`+`H` before that.

Comment: All objects except lights and cameras?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44422/how-to-select-all-using-the-keyboard

Comment: @p2or I would like to know this, also except paths etc

Answer (score 10):

To select every object in the scene press <kbd>A</kbd>. This makes to select / deselect everything depending on whether something was already selected. So if there's something already selected press <kbd>A</kbd> twice.

Note that there can be hidden objects in the scene, which won't be selected without unhiding them. You can do that by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide and then proceeding to select. See [hiding / unhiding everything but selected objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9379/hiding-all-but-the-selected-objects); also [toggling visibility of object in Outliner](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/outliner.html#toggling-object-level-restrictions).

If you'd like to select everything in scene *depending on some category* then you should use *Select Grouped* menu which can be accessed by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> when in Object mode. To select only meshes select one, access menu and choose *Type* entry. Same with any other type of objects.

[image: Select by type img]

See more about selecting in [selection tools wiki](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html#selection-tools)